# How to include rotation and scaling into Generalized Hough Transform?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am trying to implement Generalized Hough Transform for my specific research problem. 
I am trying to include rotation and scaling of the points in the reference image into the `rtable` (reference table obtained from the template image). My question is how should the data structure of `reference table (Rtable)` for this purpose?  in page 5 of [this paper](https://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS791E/Notes/GeneralizedHough.pdf), author is mentioning about a 4D table as `Rtable` (`++(P[xc][yc][θ][s])`). The following shows the algorithm:
[image]

If I have scaling factors and rotation degrees of the points for the template image as follows:

```
rf=[i*math.degrees(math.pi/4) for i in range(0,8)] #rotation factor
sf=[0.5,0.75,0.85,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,1.95]   #scaling factor
```

- How can I implement it in python and what it should be the data structure?
- Should I only create 2D array of `theta (perpendicular to gradient's direction) and r (distance from the center point of object)`, and then rotate and scale the points and recalculate their coordinate relative to the center, and include them in `Rtable`?
- What range of theta degree should be considered (binning of theta)? Is it correct only consider 0-90 degrees?

Could experts please help me in understanding with this?